# Library Information System - How to check for if BookAvailability(int) in SQL DB is NULL?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to check how many books are left in **SQL Database** before issuing one.. If there is more then 1 book available, I enter `if statement` and issue **1 book** (library information system), if there are no books, skip to else and write no books message. With this code, doesn't matter what I tried, the program skips down to else section every time.

I tried going with: (**Pseudocode**)

```
  if BookAvailability(int) == empty  > it shows NULL.
```

Replace code to check for NULL??

```
  if BookAvailability(int) != NULL > issue book.
```

Been trying to fix this for my final test since 21:00 PM... 4 AM now, still haven't find solution.. or even way to check for `NULL`, for my code...

```
   private void ButtonIssue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int book_qty = 0;

            SqlCommand cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Book_list WHERE BookName = '" + TextBoxBookName + "'";
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da2.Fill(dt2);


            SqlCommand cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT BookAvailability  FROM Book_list WHERE BookName = '" + TextBoxBookName + "'";
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
            book_qty = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da2.Fill(dt2);


            foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
            {
                book_qty = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["BookAvailability "].ToString());
            }

            if (book_qty > 0)
            {



                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO issue_book VALUES(" + TextBoxSearchMembers.Text + ",'" + TextBoxMemberName.Text + "','" + TextBoxMemberContact.Text + "','" + TextBoxMemberEmail.Text + "','" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "', '" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                SqlCommand cmd1 = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE Book_list SET BookAvailability = BookAvailability-1 WHERE BookName ='" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "'";
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


                MessageBox.Show("success");
                this.Close();

            }



            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Book not available");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There looks to be a bigger problem with your SQL logic.  You need the checks on book counts and the potential update/insert to occur within a single isolated transaction.  I would recommend getting your SQL down first, then worry about the Java code.

Comment: Not related to the question but it would be a good idea to paramaterise your queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your SQL statement to use the MySQL [IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp) function and convert all the NULLs to 0 in the query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(BookAvailability, 0) AS BookAvailability FROM Book_list ...
```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IFNULL(DostupnostKnjiga, 0) AS DostupnostKnjiga FROM Lista_knjiga WHERE ImeKnjige = '" + TextBoxNazivKnjige + "'";  => keeps giving me error. I gues i did not wrote that right..

Comment: @LazarPeric What's the error? Do you know what version of mySQL you are using?

Comment: https://ibb.co/cFuTPJ screenshot of the error. Could it be because  I'm actually using SQL not MySQL ?

Comment: If you're using sql-server the correct function is ISNULL not IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (complete code up to your if-clause):

```
private void ButtonIssue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    try
      {
        int book_qty = 0;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT BookAvailability  FROM Book_list WHERE BookName = '" + TextBoxBookName + "'";
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
        if(result != null && !DBNull.Value.Equals(result)) {
            book_qty = Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }
        if (book_qty > 0)
        // book_qty should be correct now.
```

As book_qty is 0 it will stay 0 when your result is NULL or empty. The result will be null if the book was not found or will equal DBNull.Value if the column has the value NULL, because [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) will return

> The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.

and [DBNull.Value is used for checking for null values in the database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

> To evaluate database fields to determine whether their values are DBNull, you can pass the field value to the DBNull.Value.Equals method

Remove that stuff with da2 and dt2 before trying, it will override book_qty and isn't necessary anymore if you use above approach.

If you are still not successful, please check if your BookAvailability-column is filled for books that are available and if it has type INTEGER. Also try to use the debugger to find out what exactly is in result.